# Remove whitespace in carrier info when using a navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, xcode-storyboard, carrier

I am writing a swift app and can't figure out how to get the carrier info to blend in with the color of my navigation bar. If you take a look at the image below, you will see that the carrier info is in white, while the navigation bar has a grey tint to it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Note : I am using a Tab Bar Controller.

[image: See the white space]

Comment: I was able to fix this by taking a check off of translucent for the NavigationBar. It made the navigationbar white, which isn't exactly what I wanted but at least the colors match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a UINavigationController for each tab. So "Tasks" would be the root view controller of one navigation controller and "Add Tasks" would be the root view controller of another navigation controller